# Getting undefined from javascript array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

This is linked to my previous question however its slightly different and is a whole new question... I have an array, which after some nice PHP looks like this:

```
var series = {
    "001":{
        "game":"Portal 2",
        "name":"Portal 2"
    },
    "002":{
        "game":"Minecraft",
        "name":"241"
    },
    "003":{
        "game":"Minecraft",
        "name":"HackMine"
    },
    "004":{
        "game":"Mass Effect 3",
        "name":"Mass Effect 3"
    },
    "005":{
        "game":"League of Legends",
        "name":"League of Legends"
    },
    "006":{
        "game":"Half Life 2",
        "name":"The Hidden: Source"
    },
    "007":{
        "game":"Skyrim",
        "name":"Modded Skyrim"
    }
}
```

This bit is populated fine... Now my question is when this function is called, it always gives `game` and `name` the value `undefined`

```
function seriesIdOnBlur()
{       

    var id = parseInt(document.getElementById("series_id").value);

    if (series[id] == null)
    {
        var message = "The Series ID you input was invalid";
    }
    else
    {
        var seriesId = series[id];

        var game = seriesId['game'];
        var name = seriesId['name'];
        var message = "You've inputted the id for the game: " + game + " for the series: " + name;
    }

    document.getElementById("series_id_check").innerHTML = message;
}
```

Comment: Those are not arrays. That is an object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're shooting yourself in the foot with those leading `0`s: `series['001']` is not the same as `series['1']`. Either cut the `parseInt` call (forcing the user to type '001'), drop the leading 0s:

```
var series = {
    "1":{
        "game":"Portal 2",
        "name":"Portal 2"
    },
    ...
    "7":{
        "game":"Skyrim",
        "name":"Modded Skyrim"
    }
}
```

or use an array:

```
var series = [
    {
        "game":"Portal 2",
        "name":"Portal 2"
    },
    ...
    {
        "game":"Skyrim",
        "name":"Modded Skyrim"
    }
]
```

Comment: Note that arrays are 0 based, so if you switch to the array example your first element will be at index 0 instead of "001".  If you want it to be at index 1 you can just specify your indexes and create what is called a "sparse" array: `series[1] = {"game":"Portal", "name":"Portal"};`

Comment: quick plunker for the variant without the `parseInt`: http://plnkr.co/edit/tXlIUddSKkWeIOvcQUY2?p=preview

Comment: I'm using the 00# intentionally, as eventually I will have more than 10 series, and I want the database to look neat, I don't expect to go above 999 so it's fine with the zeros... so you say to drop the parseInt

Comment: Plunker is really useful, however, on plunker it works, and on the website it doesn't any idea? Website is upload.red-jax.com

Comment: thanks I found my issue this solution did work, it was where I was getting the PHP  i surrounded it in quotes... So it was nothing to do with this error, it was me cleaning up when I posted to SO... Thanks :D

Comment: _"I want the database to look neat, I don't expect to go above 999 so it's fine with the zeros"_ - your database should know how to store and sort numbers without needing them to be sortable lexographically.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
series = {
    "001":{
        "game":"Portal 2",
        "name":"Portal 2"
    },
    "002":{
        "game":"Minecraft",
        "name":"241"
    } ... };
```

is an object literal so you have Object of Objects rather than Array of Arrays as you stated.

You will need array of objects in order your code to work:

```
series = [
    {
        "game":"Portal 2",
        "name":"Portal 2"
    },
    {
        "game":"Minecraft",
        "name":"241"
    } ... ];
```

Comment: Object of objects is fine, I thought they were arrays